# How to modify block menu path

Tags: 6, taxonomy-terms, routes, blocks, nodes

My goal is to have a menu block on my blog pages with a list of the terms used in the blog posts. So far I have set up a node view for the blog postings. And a term view called *topics* to display the terms.

It's working, but when I click on a term listed in the block the resulting path is *category/topics/term-name*. I would like to have a path such as *blog/topics/term-name* or even better just *blog/term-name*.

I have looked at the *Taxonomy menu* settings under the *taxonomy/edit/vocabulary* but haven't figured out if I can change these settings to get what I want.

I'm using the *Pathauto module*. Not sure where else to look for an answer. I'm using 6.

Answer (score 2):

Pathauto gives you the option of defining per taxonomy path patterns.  Just set the value for your blog categories taxonomy to `blog/topics/[catpath-raw]` and regenerate your aliases.  These settings are controlled in http://example.com/admin/build/path/pathauto

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I had begun to figure out it had something to so with the taxonomy paths, but wasn't sure what to do.